# overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein,R.anim.fadeout);

Tags: android

this code runs after startActivity, but setting it after:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){ 
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

keep old (default) android animation. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because by the time your activity starts and has a chance to `overridePendingTransition`, the transition has already taken place. You should change the window transitions in a `Theme`, and set the `Activity` theme at the manifest.

Comment: Cool! Thanks boy! Another thing: how keep new animation when I switch from/to other app?